# Flair não merece uma tradução?

Tags: debate, status-recusado, internacionalização

Talvez [botão](https://www.google.com/search?q=bot%C3%A3o&client=ubuntu&hs=qe5&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=33H-UsD0McujkQeoh4DoAw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1680&bih=927)? Ok, botão não é muito feliz. Mas porque não [broche](https://www.google.com/search?q=bot%C3%A3o&client=ubuntu&hs=qe5&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=33H-UsD0McujkQeoh4DoAw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1680&bih=927#channel=fs&q=broche&tbm=isch)? Ou talvez alguém com mais conhecimento em inglês que eu tenha uma palavra melhor.

Acho que se a proposta é ter o site em português, e vale para português de portugal também, deveriamos evitar alguns termos que não são estritamente necessários em ingles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei uma palavra ótima: **Condecoração**.

Comment: E **distintivo**?

Comment: É massa também. Eu gostei.

Comment: "Condecoração" eu precisaria ir ao dicionário descobrir o que é. Preferiria uma de uso comum sobre uma tradução próxima.

Comment: É bem comum em filmes de guerra. Foi a mais adequada, a meu ver.

Comment: Gostei de condecoração.

Answer (score 6):

Não consigo pensar numa tradução que transmita o sentido original de *flair*, mas que tal **crachá**?

Comment: O problema de crachá é que não sugere mérito.

Answer (score 3):

Eu lembro de ter lido em um manual de uma cadeia de restaurantes conhecida que abriu uma unidade no Brasil uma tradução dos famosos bottons, que que eles chamavam de *flair*, como *charmes*. Era um termo inclusive usado nas aplicações internas. Me pareceu simpático e adequado.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez uma tradução possível seria flâmula. No sentido de ser uma espécie de adorno (decoração) de parede.

Comment: @all se existe uma resposta aceita, eu devo usar esta tradução então? Atualmente existem algumas partes do perfil de usuário que possuem esta palavra disponível para tradução, mas não soube como traduzir adequadamente.